# Change position of view Programmatically

Tags: android, android-view

I have added xml layout to the main layout in this way:

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.anim_map_toolbar, null);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.rightMargin = 20;
    params.topMargin = 20;
    customView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(params));
View animationView = customView.findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
mainConstraintLayout.addView(customView);
```

But this layout appeared on *top and left of main layout*. I want to change the position to top right with the margin of the top and right of the main layout !!!

I have used

params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

params.rightMargin = 20;

params.topMargin = 20;

but it did not work and still view is on the right and top position !!!

This is the main layout xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main_constraintLayout">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is anim_map_toolbar.xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/animate_toolbar_style"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv_setting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings" />
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: Why are you using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` if the container is a `ConstraintLayout`? Do you really need that to be a `ConstraintLayout`? That can be a little involved, adding and arranging children programmatically.

Comment: No, I do not really need and i can change. If i changed my problem solved? @MikeM.

Comment: Well, changing to a `<FrameLayout>` should make your given code work as expected, as far as I can be sure, just giving it a read-through. However, depending on the desired final design – i.e., what all you need to add, and how you need it positioned – a `FrameLayout` might not be as capable as you need. That is, a `LinearLayout`, or `RelativeLayout`, etc., might actually be more suitable, but any of those "regular" `ViewGroup`s are going to be easier to manage programmatically than a `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According @Mikem suggest,i have changed to this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.rightMargin = 20;
        params.topMargin = 20;
        customView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and i have converted `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout` from main xml layout.

Now,my problem gone .. Thanks @Mikem